Open Crystal Report file in SpringBoot
After following the SAP Crystal Report Doc I implemented the instructions and everything to the point on execution of the function to open my basic report without datasource attached I get an error:

com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKException: com.businessobjects.sdk.erom.jrc.ReportAgentFactory---- Error code:-2147215357 [CRSDK00000026] Error code name:internal

Function:
private ByteArrayOutputStream generateCrystalReport(String reportFilePath) throws Exception {

    ReportClientDocument reportClientDocument = new ReportClientDocument();


    try {
        reportClientDocument.open(reportFilePath, 0); // Open the report
        // Perform operations with the report (e.g., export, view)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // Handle exception appropriately
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }


    // Object reportSource = reportClientDocument.getReportSource();

    // "06/24/2020 00:00:00"
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    // Export the report to a ByteArrayOutputStream
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = (ByteArrayInputStream) reportClientDocument.getPrintOutputController().export(ReportExportFormat.PDF);

    //Release report.
    reportClientDocument.close();

    //Use the Java I/O libraries to write the exported content to the file system.
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[byteArrayInputStream.available()];

    //Create a new file that will contain the exported result.
    File file = new File(EXPORT_FILE);
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(byteArrayInputStream.available());
    int x = byteArrayInputStream.read(byteArray, 0, byteArrayInputStream.available());

    byteArrayOutputStream.write(byteArray, 0, x);
    byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(fileOutputStream);

    //Close streams.
    byteArrayInputStream.close();
    byteArrayOutputStream.close();
    fileOutputStream.close();


    // Close the report
    reportClientDocument.close();

    return byteArrayOutputStream;


}

